# Using my laptop internet connection to connect other devices over Ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, gateway

My configuration is 4 Rpi's connected through a switch over Ethernet, my laptop is connected to the same switch and the switch is also connected to the Ethernet plugin in my office.

The Network administrator in my company configured MAC address filtering, where only my laptop MAC is registered and can access the internet through Ethernet, while since the Rpi's are always scaling and interchangeable we can't bug the network administrator to register a new MAC each day. The solution was Vlan but till this moment he's not responding.

My question: can I use my laptop as a default gateway to connect the Rpi's to the internet?

- Note 1: wifi hotspot is very slow for the application we are trying to implement since the communication is not only limited to the internet, the application is heavily based on communication between the Rpi's.
- Note 2: I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop and hypriotOS for the Rpi's.

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up your laptop as a proxy

Comment: Yes, you can use your laptop is gateway: Put the RPis on a VLAN segment with private IP range, activate forwarding and NAT on your laptop (google). All (non-VLAN) traffic will seem to come from your laptop. Just using it as gateway without forwarding/NAT won't work, unless you can disable ICMP redirect somehow (which I don't know how to do).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your laptop  to act as a gateway, but it is a bit more work then it sounds, and it could interfere with the network (if there is an IP range conflict) or block the RPi devices from seeing other devices (on the same subnet), but MAC filtered.

First step would be to statically assign the RPi devices Ip addresses on another subnet (172.16.x.x is often unused)

Next, bind a second IP address in the new range to the PC (ie so the NIC answers on both the main lan range and your new one). The new IP on the NIC needs to be the gateway set on the RPi's

The next bit is to enable routing.  Set up NAT ( masquerading under Linux) on the PC and turn on IP Forwarding.

Comment: An easier alternate solution might be to just get a cheap Ethernet router, clone your PC MAC onto the WAN interface and then the PC and Pi devices on to the LAN - just make sure the router supports the MAC cloning function.